# Do I need to unbind watches set in an ng-view's controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ng-view

If I have various controllers loaded via routing/`ng-view` and some of those controllers set watches, am I responsible for unregistering these watches during every route change?  Or does angular already take care of that for me via the normal controller life-cycle??

Regardless, are there any common reasons to set up an `$scope.$on("$destroy", function() { … })` aside from canceling timers?

Comment: From my understanding, I may have to unbind any browser events set on the DOM of my views too?

Comment: there's no need to unregister watches, the digest loop has got you covered. i'd suggest you have a read at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).